# IDXGISurface2::GetResource Что передается, или отдается вторым параметром?

Tags: c++, com, directx, dxgi

Я уже посмотрел заголовочный файл, и [сайт с документацией](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi1_2/nf-dxgi1_2-idxgisurface2-getresource#parameters), но так и не понял что передавать вторым параметром в метод `GetResource`?

```
MIDL_INTERFACE("aba496dd-b617-4cb8-a866-bc44d7eb1fa2")
IDXGISurface2 : public IDXGISurface1
{
public:
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetResource( 
        /* [annotation][in] */ 
        _In_  REFIID riid,
        /* [annotation][out] */ 
        _COM_Outptr_  void **ppParentResource,
        /* [annotation][out] */ 
        _Out_  UINT *pSubresourceIndex) = 0;

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вторым параметром необходимо передавать указатель на указатель на void, в который после успешного выполнения функции будет записано значение указателя на интерфейс (с глобальным идентификатором, переданным в качестве первого параметра) объекта, который был использован для создания объекта, через интерфейс `IDXGISurface2` которого вызывается этот метод.

```
 void * p_naked_interface;
 UINT index;
 HRESULT hr{p_surface->GetResource(::IID_IDXGIResource1, &p_naked_interface, &index};
 if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
 {
      ::IDXGIResource1 * p_resource{static_cast<::IDXGIResource1 *>(p_naked_interface));
      // делаем что-то с ресурсом...
      p_resource->Release();
 }
```